# Haskell - Is effect order deterministic in case of Applicative?

Tags: haskell, applicative

When executing the IO action defined by `someFun <$> (a :: IO ()) <$> (b :: IO ())`, is the execution of the `a` and `b` actions ordered? That is, can I count on that `a` is executed before `b` is?

For GHC, I can see the IO is implemented using State, and also see [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.0/System-IO.html) that it is an Applicative instance, but can't find the source of the actual instance declaration. Being implemented through State suggests that different IO effects need to be sequential, but doesn't necessary defines their ordering.

Playing around in GHCi seems that Appliative retains effect order, but is that some universal guarantee, or GHC specific? I would be interested in details.

```
import System.Time
import Control.Concurrent
import Data.Traversable
let prec (TOD a b) = b
fmap (map prec) (sequenceA $ replicate 5 (threadDelay 1000 >> getClockTime))

[641934000000,642934000000,643934000000,644934000000,645934000000]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I guess this post contains useful info but I still have to digest it: http://pchiusano.blogspot.hu/2011/07/do-side-effects-really-need-total-order.html

Comment: See http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.3.0.0/doc/html/Control-Applicative-Backwards.html, which is an applicative transformer that reverses the order of effects.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's certainly *deterministic*, yes. It will always do the same thing for any specific instance. However, there's no *inherent* reason to choose left-to-right over right-to-left for the order of effects.

However, from [the documentation for `Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html):

> If `f` is also a `Monad`, it should satisfy `pure` = `return` and `(<*>)` = `ap` (which implies that `pure` and `<*>` satisfy the applicative functor laws).

The definition of `ap` is this, from `Control.Monad`:

```
ap :: (Monad m) => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
ap =  liftM2 id
```

And `liftM2` is defined in the obvious way:

```
liftM2 f m1 m2 = do { x1 <- m1; x2 <- m2; return (f x1 x2) }
```

What this means is that, for any functor that is a `Monad` as well as an `Applicative`, it is expected (by specification, since this can't be enforced in the code), that `Applicative` will work left-to-right, so that the `do` block in `liftM2` does the same thing as `liftA2 f x y = f <$> x <*> y`.

Because of the above, even for `Applicative` instances without a corresponding `Monad`, by convention the effects are usually ordered left-to-right as well.

More broadly, because the structure of an `Applicative` computation is necessarily independent of the "effects", you can usually analyze the meaning of a program independently of how `Applicative` effects are sequenced. For example, if the instance for `[]` were changed to sequence right-to-left, any code using it would give the same results, just with the list elements in a different order.

Comment: Thank you! Do I correctly infer that if effect order is important for me and I want to be theoretical then I should use a Monad, but if I'm practical an Applicative will (usually, with care) fit?

Comment: @ron: In practice, you can simply assume that `Applicative` instances will sequence left-to-right unless they loudly announce otherwise, as with the `Backwards` wrapper. Note that `Monad` instances can also be ambiguous in other ways--for example, the reversed `State` monad threads the state value backwards, but the type itself is identical to regular `State`. For another example, `[]` has two possible `Applicative` instances even aside from the sequencing order. You can't avoid relying somewhat on what the documentation says.

Comment: @C.A.McCann "*[...] you can usually analyze the meaning of a program independently of how Applicative effects are sequenced.*" Why? Isn't that only true for *commutative* applicative functors? In general, reordering Applicative effects can change the result dramatically. Here is one example: `myParser = (++) <$> foo <*> bar` where `foo` and `bar` are parsec `Parser String`. If I changed the sequencing to right-to-left, `myParser` would fail on on input string `"foobar"`. Wouldn't you agree, in this case, that reordering of effects has affected the meaning of the program?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the order is predefined by the Monad-Applicative correspondence.  This is easy to see:  The `(*>)` combinator needs to correspond to the `(>>)` combinator in a well-behaved `Applicative` instance for a monad, and its definition is:

```
a *> b = liftA2 (const id) a b
```

In other words, if `b` were executed before `a`, the `Applicative` instance would be ill-behaving.

Edit: As a side note:  This is not explicitly specified anywhere, but you can find many other similar correspondences like `liftM2` = `liftA2`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

For the IO Applicative, this is certainly the case. But check out the [async package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async) for an example of an Applicative where in `f <$> a <*> b` the effects of `a` and `b` happen in parallel.